# Does recommence of high intensity training has influence on resting HR?

Tags: hiit, martial-arts, conditioning

The last 6 months I've done

- slow extensive runs of ± 60min, 3x / week, (HR between 145 - 155bpm)
- strength training 3x / week
- 1x/week martial art (BJJ/Muay Thai/MMA) training (technique+sparring), so without doubt HR +180bpm.

The slow extensive runs were to improve basic condition.
Strength training; to improve overall fitness during sparring.
At certain point before change of plan, my resting HR was between 49 and 55.
Changing the plan to:

- 4x / week intensive training such as martial art technique and sparring / cross-training
- 1x / week 60' slow ext. run (HR: 145-155)

Now, my resting HR stays between 54 and 60. Exercise generally lowers the resting heart rate. Does HIIT have the opposite effect?

Comment: To to clarify your question, you are specifically asking whether starting HIIT raises one's resting Heart Rate?

Comment: @SeanDuggan, yes indeed. And thanks for your answer!

Comment: I did a small edit to your question to try to make it more clear what you were asking. Feel free to edit it yourself to remove any errors I introduced. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, exercise generally [lowers one's starting heart rate](http://umm.edu/health/medical/reports/articles/exercise). [HIIT may provide superior benefits to continuous training](http://bjsm.bmj.com/content/44/Suppl_1/i20.2.abstract) (although [some disagree](https://experiencelife.com/article/steady-state-cardio-vs-high-intensity-interval-training/), saying that it's more useful when you're already at a lower HR). [Overtraining can **raise** one's resting heart rate](http://running.competitor.com/2014/06/training/think-youre-overtraining-check-your-pulse_63593) due to increased stress from your body trying to soldier on without sufficient recovery time. It sounds like you may be experiencing that. Try taking a few days rest without much exercise at all and see if that improves your morning resting Heart Rate values.

Comment: A cycling coach used to our team wear our heart rate monitors to bed. A sure-fire sign of overtraining was a resting heart beat that never found it's way back down again in the middle of the night. Hopefully those chest straps aren't as uncomfortable as they used to be.